# Wordpress: executing function when saving or editing post

Tags: wordpress, post, editing

This is what I'm trying to accomplish: 
If I'm adding or editing post I want to run a function that puts post_id, all the custom field values and category ids to some other db table I've created. 
I just want to know how to execute this function and how to get the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following in your `functions.php` file of your theme. It will run on both save as well as well update. Since you have the post ID, you can do whatever you want.

```
function do_my_stuff($post_ID)  {
   //do my stuff here;
   return $post_ID;
}

add_action('save_post', 'do_my_stuff');
```

Comment: Reference of wordpress hooks : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 0):

This was firing twice.

```
function do_my_stuff($post_ID)  {
   //do my stuff here;
   return $post_ID;
}
add_action('save_post', 'do_my_stuff');
```

Adding

```
if (wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) return;
```

to suppress revision solved it for me. Maybe you want to suppress more...

```
// API request
if (REST_REQUEST) return;

// autosave
if (wp_is_post_autosave($post_ID)) return;
```