# Track WordPress changes on post edit/save

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know how to run a function when a meta information of a custom post type is changed.

For example, I have a radio box associated with a custom post type. And made it with metaboxes, and when I change the option, I would like to run a function.

How would I do that?

Comment: Proppably You need to insert custom jQuery script to admin area that reacts on on.change of an element (or on.click).

Comment: On `save_post`, the new value should be available in the `$_POST` array, e.g. `$val = $_POST['my_metabox_value'];`

Comment: Looks like you've solved your problem, but for future searchers there are more details of the hooks available when changing metadata [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-hook-update-post-meta-and-delete-post-meta)

Comment: You might want to post your answer by clicking the "anwser your own question" and then 2 days later mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Originally in [OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16194799/revisions).*</sup>

I think I found what I wanted

```
function do_my_stuff($post_ID)  {
   //do my stuff here;
   return $post_ID;
}

add_action('save_post', 'do_my_stuff');
```

[Wordpress: executing function when saving or editing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218828/wordpress-executing-function-when-saving-or-editing-post)

But is it possible to track what changes were made?

Yup, did it with your help diggy, but had to change something.

```
function do_my_stuff($post_ID)  {
   $newvalue = $_POST['my_metabox_value'];
   echo $newvalue;
   $oldvalue= get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_metabox_value', true );
   echo $oldvalue;
}

add_action('pre_post_update', 'do_my_stuff');
```